# Unity 3d reverse float values

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, numbers, reverse, timedelta

My mini project has two buttons. A and B. When I press A the value start increasing and when I press B the values starts decreasing. My value starts from 190 and max value is 200. I have also a remaining value float. What i want is that When I press B button and my values starts decreasing, for example  my value reaches at 120. Now the remaining float will show the difference i.e. 80 (maxvalue - currentvalue). This remaining value is displayed as UI.Text. As i press A button the remaining value goes towards max value for example. 79,78,77,76 etc. But what I want is that the remaining value should be displayed on UI.text from 0 to 80 instead of 80 to 0. I hope that you understand. Please help me resolve this.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class numvalues: MonoBehaviour {



    public float current_num = 190f;
    public Text current_numtxt;
    public float max_num = 200f;
    public float remaining_num;
    public Text remaining_numtxt;

    void Start () {

    }

    void Update()
    {

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))

            current_num -= 10 * Time.deltaTime;



        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.X))

            current_num += 10 * Time.deltaTime;
            current_numtxt.text = current_num.ToString ("0");

            remaining_num = max_num - current_num; 
            remaining_numtxt.text = remaining_num.ToString ("0");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try keeping another variable lastSpeed. When you case modes, set lastSpeed as the speed you are at(120 in this case) and as you increase speed simply do currentValue - lastSpeed.